# Can I parallelize code that utilizes pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, nlp, pool

I'm doing some NLP, and need to clean my data.  I've written three functions to 1) clean the data, 2) check if the data is on topic, and 3) check of the data is english.

I have something like 8 million rows of data, and most of the computations don't rely on one another. I was thinking of parallelizing the code using Pool, but I'm not sure if that would be wise, since all the data is housed in a Pandas dataframe (I know numba doesn't play well with dataframes).

Could I parallelize my code using Pool?  Is it as simple as the code I've found in the documentation?  Is Pool even the right library?

Should note, I'm running this on Mac OSX.
Here is my code for reference:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import enchant
import numpy as np

sf = pd.read_csv('timeandtweet.csv')

def clean_tweet(x):

    cleaning = BeautifulSoup(x,"lxml")

    letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]"," ", cleaning.get_text())

    words = letters_only.lower().split()

    words = [w for w in words if not w in (stopwords.words("english")+[u'rt'])]

    return " ".join(words)



def on_topic(x):

    topics = [u'measles',u'mmr',u'vaccine',u'vaccines']

    if any(j in topics for j in x.split()):
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

def is_english(x):

    lang = enchant.Dict('en_US')
    L = len(x.split())

    words = []
    for i in x.split():
        words.append(lang.check(i))

    if float(sum(words))/L <0.6:
        return -1
    else:
        return 1





sf['Clean Tweet'] = np.zeros_like(sf.Tweet)

sf['English-Topic'] = np.zeros_like(sf.Tweet)

for i in xrange(len(sf)): #Loop instead of df.apply for speed?
    if( (i+1)%1000 == 0 ):
        print "Review %d of %d\n" % ( i+1, len(sf) ) 

    sf['Clean Tweet'][i] = clean_tweet(sf.Tweet[i])

    sf['English-Topic'][i] = (on_topic(sf['Clean Tweet'][i]), is_english(sf['Clean Tweet'][i])  )


sf.to_csv('cleaned_processed.csv', index = False)
```

My Attempt to parallelize

```
sf['Clean Tweet'] = np.zeros_like(sf.Tweet)

sf['English-Topic'] = np.zeros_like(sf.Tweet)

from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool()

result1 = pool.apply_async(clean_tweet,[sf.Tweet])
answer1 = result1.get()
```

But I keep getting a value error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: You get that ValueError on which line exactly?

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all
This error generally occurs when an index value is not given in the Dataframe. Exactly on which line are you getting the error??

Comment: Python points to `answer1 = result.get()` as the source of the error.